# MySQL Atomicity of Insert...Select Queries

Tags: mysql, atomic

Let's say I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO contest_project_entries (project_id, number) 
SELECT 17477, COUNT(*) FROM contest_project_entries WHERE project_id = 17478;
```

And say that two users made a request to the server with the query above at the same time (or almost the same time). Will the sub-query '`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contest_project_entries WHERE project_id = 17478`' return the same results on the two requests from the users?

I'm just finding out the atomicity of such queries.

Comment: Atomcity? Do you mean Anatomy?

Comment: @Ben No "Atomicity" is the right term.

Comment: Awesome, never heard that term before! It's my new favourite word.

Comment: It depends. If your question is oriented on whether it's possible that 2 results are different - yes, it is. Assuming InnoDB is used, both queries will use a snapshot of the dataset and receive the same value for count query if they're executed in such time that both received the same value of the dataset snapshot. Also, it's got nothing to do with atomicity, if by atomicity we assume that it means that either all queries succeed or nothing happens.

Comment: It also depends critically on what the transaction isolation is for both sessions.